# how to compare the current system time with two timing?

Tags: java

i want to get the current system time and compare with the two different timing example startwindow time as 2:00:00AM and endWindowTime as 6:00:00AM. if my current system time falls between these window i have to execute my rest of the code.

my below code works for fine for JAVA 1.6 version when i do the same code with JAVA 1.4 i am getting different date and time

```
  String starTime=(String) NightlyvendorStatus[0].getPropertyValue("startTime");
  String endTime=(String) NightlyvendorStatus[0].getPropertyValue("endTime");
  Date windowStarttime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(starTime);
  Date windowEndtime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(endTime);

  Date systemdate = new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
  String systemTime=parser.format(systemdate);
  Date currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(systemTime);

  if (currentTime.after(windowStarttime) && currentTime.before(windowEndtime))
                                                                                                                        {   ---- ---- other code ----}
```

the output from JAVA 1.4 IS

```
Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 GMT 1970
Thu Jan 01 06:00:00 GMT 1970
Thu Jan 01 03:23:00 GMT 1970
```

HOW TO DO this logic..

Comment: The given code doesn't produce output, so I don't see what you mean by "output from JAVA 1.4".

Comment: What those outputs mean? Is it a start time or end time or systime?

Comment: For the love of god, stop instantiating new SimpleDateFormats. You have the right idea when you save it as 'parser' -- why not just use that everywhere?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  3:23am on 1/1/70 is indeed between 2:00am on 1/1/70 and 6:00am on 1/1/70.

Comment: Looks fine to me. What exactly is the problem/question?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
String starTime = "22:00:00";
String endTime = "23:00:00";

SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

Calendar windowStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
windowStartTime.setTime(parser.parse(starTime));
windowStartTime.set(0, 0, 0);

Calendar windowEndTime = Calendar.getInstance();
windowEndTime.setTime(parser.parse(endTime));
windowEndTime.set(0, 0, 0);

// This covers if time window is crosses days. Ex: 11:00PM to 2:00AM
if(windowStartTime.after(windowEndTime)) {
    windowEndTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
currentTime.set(0, 0, 0);

System.out.println("Current Time: " + currentTime.getTime().toString());
System.out.println("Start Time: " + windowStartTime.getTime().toString());
System.out.println("End Time: " + windowEndTime.getTime().toString());

if(currentTime.after(windowStartTime) && currentTime.before(windowEndTime)) {
    System.out.println("Between Time Window");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Between Time Window");
}
```

The reason I do:

```
windowStartTime.set(0, 0, 0);
windowEndTime.set(0, 0, 0);
currentTime.set(0, 0, 0);
```

Is to put all the Calendars on the same day.